# He almost drowned(,) when he swam across the river(,) because of the bees

Tags: grammar, punctuation, semantics, reference

What is the difference in meaning between

1. He almost drowned when he swam across the river because of the bees.
2. He almost drowned, when he swam across the river because of the bees.
3. He almost drowned when he swam across the river, because of the bees.
4. He almost drowned, when he swam across the river, because of the bees.

Is it clear whether the bees attacked him on the shore and he tried to get away from them by jumping into the water, or they approached and attacked him while he was swimming?

The sentence was created by a friend of mine.

Comment: (3) and (4) imply that the bees caused the near-drowning rather than being the reason for the swim.

Comment: @KateBunting Your input is always clear and to the point! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Without context, any of these are likely to be misread.  Commas are easy to miss.

You shouldn't put a comma after "river".  You might put a comma after "drowned". It's not needed for the grammar, but might help the meaning.

Better would be to rephrase.  Put the bees first. Use two, or more, sentences.

Comment: Definitely want something like: "He swam across the river because of the bees and almost drowned." (Although I'm sure that could be improved.) The order of the sentence(s) should somewhat resemble the order that things actually happened:  the original sentence puts the events in reverse order.

Comment: Possibly "Because of the bees, he swam across the river and almost drowned [in the process]".

Comment: I'd say something like "The bees attacked him on the bank of river. He tried to escape them by jumping in the water, and almost drowned"  (which is pretty much what the OP wrote in the question)

Comment: How would 'a comma after "drowned"' 'help the meaning'? How do the commas change the meaning?

Comment: It would help by separating the part about bees from the part about swimming and growing.  **But** please read the last paragraph very carefully:  "Better would be to rephrase".  Your sentence is not so good, and putting in some commas doesn't help much.